# How to destroy 'Popstate' event listener?

Tags: javascript, popstate, removeeventlistener

Have tried Below Code but its not destroying `Popstate Event`.

Please help we with the example in which i can destroy the `Popstate Event` based on the condition.

```
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
  if (true){
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    console.log('Back Button Prevented');
  } else {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', ()=> {
          console.log('Go back');
      }, true);
      history.back();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to remove a listener, you have to pass the listener function itself to `removeEventListener()`.

Another problem in your code is that with the use of `if (true)`, you'll never reach the `else` block that is removing the listener. What you'll probably want to do is have a boolean variable outside of the listener that you change on the first call of the listener.

```
var backButtonPrevented = false;
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);

function popStateListener(event) {
  if (backButtonPrevented === false){
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    console.log('Back Button Prevented');
    backButtonPrevented = true;
  } else {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', popStateListener);
      history.back();
  }
}

window.addEventListener('popstate', popStateListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument you pass to `removeEventListener` has to be **the function you want to remove**.

You are passing a *different* function, which hasn't been registered as an event handler, so nothing happens.

Declare your event handler as a function with a reference you can reuse. Then use that reference for **both** `removeEventListener` and `addEventListener`.

```
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);

function myEventListener (event) { 
  if (true){
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    console.log('Back Button Prevented');
  } else {

      window.removeEventListener('popstate', myEventListener);
      history.back();
  }
}

window.addEventListener('popstate', myEventListener);
```

Comment: He did add an example, it's right there in his answer. :)